# Font-weight in local Windows environment

Tags: windows, css, fonts, font-face

I'm using Windows 10 and reformatted my computer the other day.

What isn't new is that sometimes Windows will combine font families (i.e. Arial Black, Arial Bold, Arial Narrow, et cetera) into one "file".

**What is new, however, it will not allow me to change the `font-weight` property to make use of different weights when developing locally now.** Before I could change the value of `font-weight` to, say, `600` (or `700` or `lighter` or `bold` or whatever) and the type would change accordingly.

For what it's worth, I'm using `@font-face` and have imported the font to the desired folder. I've tried creating separate `@font-face` declarations for the individual font names, which didn't work. For instance...

```
@font-face {
  font-family: bahn;
  src: url('../bahnschrift.ttf') format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: bahn-light;
  src: url('../bahnschrift light.ttf') format('truetype');
}

/* etc */
```

**Any idea how to fix this??**